# How to launch N tasks (or threads) to run the same method that may return useless results?

Tags: c#, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I have a few stochastic functions that returns a `Maybe<T>`. When it produces a useful result, Maybe contains the result.

`Maybe<T>` is implemented like this:

```
public readonly struct Maybe<T> {

    public readonly bool ContainsValue;
    public readonly T Value;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public Maybe(bool containsValue, T value) {
        ContainsValue = containsValue;
        Value = value;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Maybe<T> Just(T value) {
        return new Maybe<T>(
            containsValue: true,
            value: value);
    }

    public static Maybe<T> Empty { get; } = new Maybe<T>(
        containsValue: false,
        value: default
        );

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value) => Maybe.Just(value);
}
```

I'd like to spawn create N tasks to run `FuncThatMayFail()`, with N = `Environment.ProcessorCount`. When the first task / thread actually get a useful result, it stops and tells the other tasks / threads to stop too.

My current approach is this:

```
public static Maybe<T> RunParallel<T>(int maximumRetries, Func<Maybe<T>> func) {
    if (maximumRetries < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maximumRetries) + " must be >= 0");
    if (func == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));

    var retries = 0;
    var tasks = new Task<Maybe<T>>[Environment.ProcessorCount];
    var finished = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++) {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => {
            while (true) {
                if (retries >= maximumRetries || finished > 0)
                    return Maybe<T>.Empty;

                var attempt = func();
                if (attempt.ContainsValue) {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref finished);
                    return attempt;
                } else {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref retries);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Task.WaitAny(tasks);

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++) {
        var t = tasks[i];
        if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully && t.Result.ContainsValue)
            return t.Result;
    }

    return Maybe<T>.Empty;
}
```

I posted this on codereview asking for improvement suggestions and got none.
I feel this code is ugly and that there probably is a better way to do this.
Is there a more elegant (without using external libraries) to achieve this?
I'm using C# 7.2 targeting .Net Core 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the code and posted it below.  It's not tested but the answer is in there.  You should be able to run as is but if not take what you need out of it.

- First you need to add a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass the `Token` to the `Task`(s)
  started so that you can signal them when to stop (from the frameworks
  perspective).
- Then you need to monitor that `CancellationTokenSource` yourself in the `while` loop to manually stop the tasks.
- `Task.WaitAny` returns the index of the `Task` that was
  completed so you don't need to iterate through them to find it.
- You're also already returning `Maybe<T>.Empty` if the `Task`
  ends without a result so no need to test `ContainsValue`; just
  return the `Result`.

Code is below and documented where I made changes.

```
//Make a cancellation token source to signal other tasks to cancel.
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => {
        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested) //Monitor for the cancellation token source to signal canceled.
        {
            if (retries >= maximumRetries || finished > 0)
                return Maybe<T>.Empty;

            var attempt = func();
            if (attempt.ContainsValue)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref finished);
                return attempt;
            }
            else
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref retries);
            }
        }
        return Maybe<T>.Empty;
    }, cts.Token); //Add the token to the task.
}

var completedTaskIndex = Task.WaitAny(tasks); //Task.WaitAny gives you the index of the Task that did complete.
cts.Cancel(); //Signal the remaining tasks to complete.
var completedTask = tasks[completedTaskIndex]; //Get the task that completed.
return completedTask.Result; //You're returning Maybe<T>.Emtpy from the Task if it fails so no need to check ContainsValue; just return the result.
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I didn't notice .WaitAny returned the index.

Comment: np, glad it helped.